# Select Only Non-Matches Using Single Query (Joins Only)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a pretty simple many-to-many table structure (see below) in SQL Server (T-SQL).

I need to:

- Select all jobs that don't have an associated person
- Select all jobs that are only associated with people who are not visible and/or are deleted
- Select all jobs that are deleted.

All of this should return a single table of results

Is this possible in a single join-only query (without using `IN`/`NOT IN`, nested selects, unions, or temp tables, etc)?

**SCHEMA**:

**Person**

```
  ID
  IsVisible
  IsDeleted
```

**PersonJobs**

```
  PersonID
  JobID
```

**Jobs**

```
  ID
  IsDeleted
```

I should be able to do each query individually, then join the dataset in code, but I was curious if there's simpler way to do this using joins.

Pseudo code is fine in response, if accurate.

Thanks!

Comment: user2864740 unfortunately they're all restrictions from C#'s SubSonic (no UNION support and IN/NOT IN are limited to 2100 items [due to parameterized queries]).  I could easily write SubSonic inline queries to accomplish this, or select individually and build the unions myself, but I figured I'd ask before jumping to a conclusion :)

Comment: Is this question about *TSQL* or *SubSonic*? :> Anyway, consider creating a View - then all the "complicated" stuff is kept in a shiny little sealed bundle with a refined interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select j.*
from personjobs pj
full join jobs j on pj.jobid = j.id
full join person p on pj.personid = p.id
where pj.personid is null
or p.isdeleted = 1
or p.isvisible = 0
or j.isdeleted = 1
```

Comment: Wouldn't this have potential to get a job that is not associated with one physician, but is associated with another?

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` statement is used for identification of the given condition of each raw. If you don't need to know them simply remove it.

```
Select J.Id, CASE WHEN PersonVisible Is Null THEN '1 - Not Associated'
                  WHEN PersonVisible = 1 OR PersonDeleted = 1 THEN '2 - Person NotVisible/Deleted'
                  WHEN J.Deleted = 1 THEN '3 - Deleted Jobs'
             ELSE '4 - All Except above' END as Conditions
From Jobs J Left Join
    (Select jobId,IsVisible PersonVisible, IsDeleted PersonDeleted
     From Person p join PersonJobs pj on p.Id = pj.personId
    ) X On J.Id = X.jobId
Order by Conditions
```

Comment: I think OP has mentioned Nested Selects are not valid. also the logic is also not right for second requirement line. "Select all jobs that are only associated with people who are not visible and/or are deleted" what I understand from this is if the JOB has any visible and/or Non_Deleted PersonID associated with it that should not be part of the select. But the query you posted will not do that.